# Vue model only updating when input element lose focus

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new to vue, i am trying to integrate an ajax search when a keyup event fires, i tried to print the value, but it seems like model is updating only when the input element lost its focus.

**HTML**

```
<input name="search" placeholder="Search" type="search" 
    @keyup="whenkeyup" @focus="searchResult" 
    @blur="hideResult" 
    v-model="searchvalue">
<button type="submit">&nbsp;</button>
<span>
{{ searchvalue }}
</span>
```

**JS**

```
var search = new Vue({
  el: '#header',
     data: {
         searchvalue :'',
     },
    methods: {
        whenkeyup: function() {
            //ajax call
            console.log(this.searchvalue);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i can get the value by, $event.target.value. but i feels like this is not the vue way to do things.

Comment: In addition to @gurghet's answer, when implementing ajax search in vuejs, you can specify debouce attribute on your input to prevent it from firing ajax requests too frequently. ([vue-debounce](https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#debounce))

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the change instead of keyup